# Regular Expression to match most explicit string

Tags: regex

I have some experience with regular expressions but I am far from expert level and need a way to match the record with the most explicit string in a file where each record begins with a unique 1-5 digit integer and is padded with various other characters when it is shorter than 5 digits. For example, my file has records that begin with:

```
32000
3201X
32014
320xy
```

In this example, the non-numeric characters represent wildcards. I thought the following regex examples would work but rather than match the record with the MOST explicit number, they always match the record with the LEAST explicit number. Remember, I do not know what is in the file so I need to test all possibilities to locate the MOST explicit match.

```
If I need to search for 32000, the regex looks something like:
    /^3\D{4}|^32\D{3}|^320\D{2}|^3200\D|^32000/
  It should match 32000 but it matches 320xy

If I need to search for 32014, the regex looks something like:
    /^3\D{4}|^32\D{3}|^320\D{2}|^3201\D|^32014/
  It should match 32014 but it matches 320xy

If I need to search for 32015, the regex looks something like:
    /^3\D{4}|^32\D{3}|^320\D{2}|^3201\D|^32015/
  It should match 3201x but it matches 320xy
```

In each case, the matched result is the LEAST specific numeric value. I also tried reversing the regex as follows by still get the same results:
    /^32014|^3201\D|^320\D{2}|^32\D{3}|^3\D{4}/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Regular expression does not return anything, it is a pattern that can match some text. If you have no `x` or `y` after `123`, the match or capturing groups won't hold these characters. What programming language are you using?

Comment: My apologies...Did not mean to state I want something returned...I am looking for a match and then I will extract what I need. Currently, I am just trying to formulate a regex to do this in Notepad++ but will eventually be using JavaScript.

Comment: It is still a bit unclear: do you mean to match the first 1-5 digits on a line? Try `(?m)[0-9]{1,5}\b`. This will match 1-5 digits at the beginning of a line with the digit sequences being "full words".

Comment: I am not looking to match ANY 1-5 digits but rather a literal value. The problem is sometimes I have a full 5 digit number such as 12345 and that will match a string of 12345. But in other cases, I only have a 2 digit number such as 12. In this case, it needs to match a string of 12xxx but not 123xy or 1234x or 12345. I tried something like /^12345|^1234|^123|^12|^1/ but this matches any value beginning with 1

Comment: Maybe this will help...Using /^1\D{4}|^12\D{3}|^123\D{2}|^1234\D|^12345/ matches 12xxx but what I need is a match of 12345 (most explicit). If 12345 was not in the file, then next explicit would be 1234x

Comment: What type of character is in the 6th position?  A delimiter?

Comment: Are you aware that \D means NOT a digit?  \d is a digit. That's why ^320\D{2} matches 320xy.

Comment: The 6th position is a vertical bar (|) and yes, I am aware that \D means not a digit. Referring to my original post (which has been updated), ^320\D{2} will match any string beginning with 320 and followed by 2 non-digits. So if I need to find the most explicit match for 32017, I need the regex to match the 3201x record (most explicit matching digits) but it is matching the 320xy record (least explicit).

Comment: I realize I can do this with five separate searches: ^32017, then ^3201\D, then ^320\D{2}, then ^32\D{3} and finally ^3\D{4} but the goal is to get this working with a single search since the file is very large and performance will be slow with separate searches.

Comment: It is a little hard to understand what you are saying. What do you mean by "It should match 32000 but it matches 320xy". It matches both...

Comment: You are correct that it matches both but if I use the regex to search from the beginning of the file, it ALWAYS produces a match on the record 320xy. It never results in a match on 32000. I need it to only choose a less explicit match when there is no more explicit match. In this case, 32000 is more explicit. In other words, if I need to find a record that matches 32000. If 32000 exists, that should be the result. If it doesn't then 320xy should be the result.

Comment: I'm running out of ways to describe this...I have a file with many records that start with 5 character strings which consist of 1-5 digits padded with non-numerics as wildcards. So I have a string, 32000, and I need to locate the record that most closely matches it by numeric significance. Most significant would be a 100% match of 32000. If that record doesn't exist, see if there is a matching one that starts with 3200 followed by an arbitrary non-numeric. If not, see if there is one that starts with 320 and 2 non-numerics. And so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did quite some tinkering here. I am 99% percent sure that this is pretty much impossible (if we don't cheat and interpolate code into the regex). The reason is you will need a negative lookbehind with variable length at some point.

However, I came up with two alternatives. One is if you want just to find the "most exact match", the second one is if you want to replace it with something. Here we go:

```
/(32000)|\A(?!.*32000).*(3200\D)|\A(?!.*3200[0\D]).*(320\D\D)|\A(?!.*320[0\D][0\D]).*(32\D\D\D)|\A(?!.*32[0\D][0\D][0\D]).*(3\D\D\D\D)/m
```

Question:

> So what is my "most exact match" here?

Answer:

> The concatenation of the 5 matched groups - `\1\2\3\4\5`. In fact always only one of them will match, the other 4 will be empty.

```
/(32000)|\A(?!.*32000)(.*)(3200\D)|\A(?!.*3200[0\D])(.*)(320\D\D)|\A(?!.*320[0\D][0\D])(.*)(32\D\D\D)|\A(?!.*32[0\D][0\D][0\D])(.*)(3\D\D\D\D)/m
```

Question:

> How can I use this to replace my "most exact match"?

Answer:

> In this case your "most exact match" will be the concatenation of `\1\3\5\7\9`, but we will have also matched some other things before that, namely `\2\4\6\8` (again, only one of these can be non empty). Therefore if you want to replace your "most exact match" with `fubar` you can match with the above regex and replace with `\2\4\6\8fubar`

Another way you can think about it (and might be helpful) is that your "most exact match" will be the last matched line of either of the two regexes.

Two things to note here:

- I used Ruby style RE, `\A` means the beginning of the string (not the beginning of a line - `^`). `\m` means multi line mode. You should be able to find syntax for the same things in your language/technology as long as it uses some flavor of PCRE.
- This can be slow. If we don't find exact match we might possibly have to match and replace the entire string (if the non exact match can be found at the end of the string).

Comment: Wow! I'm guessing you spent a lot of time on this and I appreciate it very much. I won't even pretend to understand what this does but it is not quite right. Given the four records in my original post, if I modify the expressions you provided to search for the "most exact match" to the string 32005, it returns not found but it needs to match 320xy.

Comment: It works, the regex just needs to be modified in 5 places (most to least exact matches). The 32005 regex will look like this: `/(32005)|\A(?!.*32005).*(3200\D)|\A(?!.*3200[5\D]).*(320\D\D)|\A(?!.*320[0\D][5\D]).*(32\D\D\D)|\A(?!.*32[0\D][0\D][5\D]).*(3\D\D\D\D)/m`. You can see the result here: http://rubular.com/r/PQGD59UaeD

Comment: Indeed it does! I must have had fat fingers last night.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you want to match a string literally then use anchors.  Then specify the string you want matched.  For instance match '123456xyz' where the xyz can be anything excep numeric use:

```
'^123456[^0-9]{3}$'
```

If you prefer specific letters to match at the end, if they will always be x y or z then use:

```
'^123456[xyz]{3}$'
```

Note the ^ and $ anchor the string to start with 12345 and end with three letters that are x y or z.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I guess I'm not being very clear. I must be able to locate a SPECIFIC numeric value such as 12345, or 65237, or 65 followed by three arbitrary non-numeric characters. I will be able to programatically alter the literal search string in the regex. For example, if I have two records in my file that begin with 65237 and 65xyy where x and yy are wildcards. If I need a match for 65123, the regex should match 65xyy.

Comment: I am still not being clear...I will update my original question with better examples.